# Android Example for Mastercard Payments API

Tags: android

Can anyone suggest me a tutorial  or blog explaining Examples using Mastercard Payments API in an Android Application.

**I am looking for examples other than those from developer.mastercard.com**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer this site you got some idea

https://developer.mastercard.com/portal/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14876685

Comment: This serves the need!!! But isn't it for an Older version of the API?

Comment: @SanjayD Did you end up using this and how did it go? Also does it support Visa and other cards?